# C# Modifying the root dictionary, in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference

---

I have a class that contains several dictionaries, this is the general structure:

```
    public class DictionaryInit_BS {
        public Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup> C = new Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>()
        {
            {100030, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="C"}},
            {100033, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="C"}},
        };
        public Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup> E = new Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>()
        {
            {105000, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="E"}},
            {110302, new DictionaryCheckup {theGrouping="E"}},
        };
    }
```

As you can see, there are several dictionaries with letters for names, these letters(dictionaries) are then selected by the user from a combo box, to choose which dictionary they wish to modify.

**This is how I create the dictionary of dictionaries:**

```
            SelectedDictionary = cmbDictionList.Text;
            TheBSDictionary = new DictionaryInit_BS();
            var DictionaryofDictionaries = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup>>();
            var C = TheBSDictionary.C;
            var E = TheBSDictionary.E;
            var T = TheBSDictionary.T;
            DictionaryofDictionaries.Add("C", C);
            DictionaryofDictionaries.Add("E", E);
            DictionaryofDictionaries.Add("T", T);
            DictionaryofDictionaries.TryGetValue(SelectedDictionary, out Dictionary<int, DictionaryCheckup> Found_Dictionary);
```

This is the part i'm having trouble with. My out variable, Found_Dictionary, does not return the value of the root dictionary and instead returns an instance of it, so that when I do something like `Found_Dictionary.Clear();`  I want it to clear the dictionary in the class above.

(Example: IF SelectedDictionary is T, and I do `Found_Dictionary.Clear();`, TheBSDictionary.T should be cleared, not this new dictionary Found_Dictionary)

So, my question is, how do I reference the chosen dictionary, after it is chosen, such that I can modify it permanently as if I were modifying it directly(if I were to pull the values of TheBSDictionary.T, it would be the modified values), and as a follow up question, the main intention of this code is so that the user could permanently modify the structure of a selected dictionary. Is there a way, such that when I clear the dictionary this way, it will remain cleared when the program is restarted?

The reason I don't just use a new dictionary for these is that I wish to keep the structure of the data.

Comment: DictionaryCheckup is a class and not a dictionary.  You can make it inherit the dictionary class : DictionaryCheckup : IDictionary<>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'd like to ask you to elaborate why I would want to inherit it. Sorry, it isn't immediately obvious to me! As far as the code goes, it's just another set of strings. @jdweng

Comment: A dictionary  consists of KeyPairValues and you have a class DictionaryCheckup that need two items : Key and Value.  Right now DictionaryCheckup is a class with out a key and value.